# unable to start r studio due to large file in directory

Tags: r, rstudio

I am unable to start R studio because I had saved a large file in my rdata when closing R studio during a previous session. Is there a way to start R studio without loading this file in? The file is ~4gb.

Thank you for your help!

Scott

Comment: ...delete the file?

Comment: Or move it to a new directory. Then in Rstudio, you can tell it to not read in files in Tools > Global Options General. I turn of "Re-use idle sessions...", "Restore most recently used ...", "Restore .RData into" (this is probably turned on for you), and set "Save workspace ..." to Never. Just my preferences.

Comment: by the way, if you move your .Rdata, you can may later reload it to retrieve its content.

Comment: Moving the directory solved the problem -- thank you for your help!